# How do I use GTK4's ColumnView to replace TreeView in Python?

Tags: python, gtk4

I'm converting a Python (3.10) application from GTK3 to GTK4, and I would like to move away from `TreeView`/`CellRenderer` usage, and try to use `ColumnView` instead.  I've read the [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/section-list-widget.html) on GTK4's new list widgets, read their [blog post](https://blog.gtk.org/2020/09/21/gtkcolumnview/) about them, searched for examples, and am still quite confused.

As I understand it, a `ColumnView` has a single model (i.e. `Gtk.SingleSelection`), which itself is based on a `GListModel` (i.e. `Gio.ListStore`).  `Gio.ListStore` does not accept a list, like a `Gtk.ListStore` does, so my question is, **how do I store data for multiple columns, when the model (Gio.ListStore) doesn't accept a list?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own `Gobject.Object` to put into the `Gio.ListStore`
and then make your own factory to get those items. For example, I have a custom object defined as follows:

```
class FamilieRow(GObject.Object):
    familie: str
    anzahl: int

    def __init__(self, familie: str, anzahl: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.familie = familie
        self.anzahl = anzahl
```

The `Gio.ListStore` then stores those items:

```
ls = Gio.ListStore()
ls.append(FamilieRow("Steffens", 15))
```

To populate the row `familie` the factory is defined as

```
factory = Gtk.SignalListItemFactory()
factory.connect("setup", lambda _fact, item:
    item.set_child(Gtk.Label(halign=Gtk.Align.START))
factory.connect("bind", lambda _fact, item:
    item.get_child().set_label(item.get_item().familie))

col_f = Gtk.ColumnViewColumn(
        title="Familie",
        factory=factory,
)
```

If you wanted to change more than just the label, it could be inconvenient
to use a lambda. Then you could let
the custom object itself set up the widget by defining

```
factory.bind("bind", lambda _fact, item: item.get_item().bind_familie(item.get_child()))
```

and defining a `bind_familie` method on your row object

```
class FamilieRow(GObject.Object):
    ...
    def bind_familie(self, label: Gtk.Label, column: str):
        label.set_label(self.familie)
        label.set_style_classes(["big"] if self.anzahl > 40 else [])
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't perfectly answer your question for python but I made an example of a ColumnView with gtk4-rs (rust) https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/pull/1111

I use ListStore.append(...) for many items (structs) and then have columnview factory functions that pick the element from the struct to display in a particular column