# Creating a TreeView using modern GTK4 without using deprecated functions

Tags: c, treeview, gtk4

Now this is a question for programming in C with GTK4.

This is about creating a TreeView. In the GTK4 samples, it contains a `GtkListStore`, which contains the following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS

static GtkWidget *window = NULL;
static GtkTreeModel *model = NULL;
static guint timeout = 0;

typedef struct
{
  const gboolean  fixed;
  const guint     number;
  const char     *severity;
  const char     *description;
} Bug;

enum
{
  COLUMN_FIXED,
  COLUMN_NUMBER,
  COLUMN_SEVERITY,
  COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
  COLUMN_PULSE,
  COLUMN_ICON,
  COLUMN_ACTIVE,
  COLUMN_SENSITIVE,
  NUM_COLUMNS
};

static Bug bugs[] =
{
  { FALSE, 60482, "Normal",     "scrollable notebooks and hidden tabs" },
  { FALSE, 60620, "Critical",   "gdk_surface_clear_area (gdksurface-win32.c) is not thread-safe" },
  { FALSE, 50214, "Major",      "Xft support does not clean up correctly" },
  { TRUE,  52877, "Major",      "GtkFileSelection needs a refresh method. " },
  { FALSE, 56070, "Normal",     "Can't click button after setting in sensitive" },
  { TRUE,  56355, "Normal",     "GtkLabel - Not all changes propagate correctly" },
  { FALSE, 50055, "Normal",     "Rework width/height computations for TreeView" },
  { FALSE, 58278, "Normal",     "gtk_dialog_set_response_sensitive () doesn't work" },
  { FALSE, 55767, "Normal",     "Getters for all setters" },
  { FALSE, 56925, "Normal",     "Gtkcalender size" },
  { FALSE, 56221, "Normal",     "Selectable label needs right-click copy menu" },
  { TRUE,  50939, "Normal",     "Add shift clicking to GtkTextView" },
  { FALSE, 6112,  "Enhancement","netscape-like collapsible toolbars" },
  { FALSE, 1,     "Normal",     "First bug :=)" },
};

static gboolean
spinner_timeout (gpointer data)
{
  GtkTreeIter iter;
  guint pulse;

  if (model == NULL)
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;

  gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first (model, &iter);
  gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter,
                      COLUMN_PULSE, &pulse,
                      -1);
  if (pulse == G_MAXUINT)
    pulse = 0;
  else
    pulse++;

  gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE (model),
                      &iter,
                      COLUMN_PULSE, pulse,
                      COLUMN_ACTIVE, TRUE,
                      -1);

  return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}

static GtkTreeModel *
create_model (void)
{
  int i = 0;
  GtkListStore *store;
  GtkTreeIter iter;

  /* create list store */
  store = gtk_list_store_new (NUM_COLUMNS,
                              G_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                              G_TYPE_UINT,
                              G_TYPE_STRING,
                              G_TYPE_STRING,
                              G_TYPE_UINT,
                              G_TYPE_STRING,
                              G_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                              G_TYPE_BOOLEAN);

  /* add data to the list store */
  for (i = 0; i < G_N_ELEMENTS (bugs); i++)
    {
      const char *icon_name;
      gboolean sensitive;

      if (i == 1 || i == 3)
        icon_name = "battery-caution-charging-symbolic";
      else
        icon_name = NULL;
      if (i == 3)
        sensitive = FALSE;
      else
        sensitive = TRUE;
      gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
      gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                          COLUMN_FIXED, bugs[i].fixed,
                          COLUMN_NUMBER, bugs[i].number,
                          COLUMN_SEVERITY, bugs[i].severity,
                          COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, bugs[i].description,
                          COLUMN_PULSE, 0,
                          COLUMN_ICON, icon_name,
                          COLUMN_ACTIVE, FALSE,
                          COLUMN_SENSITIVE, sensitive,
                          -1);
    }

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL (store);
}

static void
fixed_toggled (GtkCellRendererToggle *cell,
               char                  *path_str,
               gpointer               data)
{
  GtkTreeModel *tree_model = (GtkTreeModel *)data;
  GtkTreeIter  iter;
  GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string (path_str);
  gboolean fixed;

  /* get toggled iter */
  gtk_tree_model_get_iter (tree_model, &iter, path);
  gtk_tree_model_get (tree_model, &iter, COLUMN_FIXED, &fixed, -1);

  /* do something with the value */
  fixed ^= 1;

  /* set new value */
  gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE (tree_model), &iter, COLUMN_FIXED, fixed, -1);

  /* clean up */
  gtk_tree_path_free (path);
}

static void
add_columns (GtkTreeView *treeview)
{
  GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column;

  /* column for fixed toggles */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_toggle_new ();
  g_signal_connect (renderer, "toggled",
                    G_CALLBACK (fixed_toggled), model);

  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Fixed?",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "active", COLUMN_FIXED,
                                                     NULL);

  /* set this column to a fixed sizing (of 50 pixels) */
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sizing (GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN (column),
                                   GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_fixed_width (GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN (column), 50);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);

  /* column for bug numbers */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Bug number",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "text",
                                                     COLUMN_NUMBER,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id (column, COLUMN_NUMBER);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);

  /* column for severities */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Severity",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "text",
                                                     COLUMN_SEVERITY,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id (column, COLUMN_SEVERITY);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);

  /* column for description */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Description",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "text",
                                                     COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id (column, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);

  /* column for spinner */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_spinner_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Spinning",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "pulse",
                                                     COLUMN_PULSE,
                                                     "active",
                                                     COLUMN_ACTIVE,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id (column, COLUMN_PULSE);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);

  /* column for symbolic icon */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Symbolic icon",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "icon-name",
                                                     COLUMN_ICON,
                                                     "sensitive",
                                                     COLUMN_SENSITIVE,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id (column, COLUMN_ICON);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);
}

static gboolean
window_closed (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
{
  model = NULL;
  window = NULL;
  if (timeout != 0)
    {
      g_source_remove (timeout);
      timeout = 0;
    }
  return FALSE;
}

GtkWidget *
do_list_store (GtkWidget *do_widget)
{
  if (!window)
    {
      GtkWidget *vbox;
      GtkWidget *label;
      GtkWidget *sw;
      GtkWidget *treeview;

      /* create window, etc */
      window = gtk_window_new ();
      gtk_window_set_display (GTK_WINDOW (window),
                              gtk_widget_get_display (do_widget));
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "List Store");
      g_object_add_weak_pointer (G_OBJECT (window), (gpointer *)&window);

      vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 8);
      gtk_widget_set_margin_start (vbox, 8);
      gtk_widget_set_margin_end (vbox, 8);
      gtk_widget_set_margin_top (vbox, 8);
      gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom (vbox, 8);
      gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), vbox);

      label = gtk_label_new ("This is the bug list (note: not based on real data, it would be nice to have a nice ODBC interface to bugzilla or so, though).");
      gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vbox), label);

      sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new ();
      gtk_scrolled_window_set_has_frame (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (sw), TRUE);
      gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (sw),
                                      GTK_POLICY_NEVER,
                                      GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
      gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vbox), sw);

      /* create tree model */
      model = create_model ();

      /* create tree view */
      treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (model);
      gtk_widget_set_vexpand (treeview, TRUE);
      gtk_tree_view_set_search_column (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview),
                                       COLUMN_DESCRIPTION);

      g_object_unref (model);

      gtk_scrolled_window_set_child (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (sw), treeview);

      /* add columns to the tree view */
      add_columns (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview));

      /* finish & show */
      gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 280, 250);
      g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (window_closed), NULL);
    }

  if (!gtk_widget_get_visible (window))
    {
      gtk_widget_set_visible (window, TRUE);
      if (timeout == 0) {
        /* FIXME this should use the animation-duration instead */
        timeout = g_timeout_add (80, spinner_timeout, NULL);
      }
    }
  else
    {
      gtk_window_destroy (GTK_WINDOW (window));
      window = NULL;
      if (timeout != 0)
        {
          g_source_remove (timeout);
          timeout = 0;
        }
    }

  return window;
}
```

But the functions that are used in this code are deprecated, and some even state in the docs "do not to use this code in new projects" or something like that.

Now my question is, how do I make something like this in GTK4 without using the deprecated functions? And how do I approach this? I've noticed there's a ColumnView function, is this a good replacement for adding items into a list with columns?

This question I'm asking is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76711050/how-to-create-a-treeview-like-ui-using-columnview-in-gtk4) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145916/how-do-i-use-gtk4s-columnview-to-replace-treeview-in-python), except this is in C.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just look at the Python code you referenced, it’s very readable and translate all ideas to get easyly

Comment: I certainly will look again, thank you so much!